# I Need to Add few columns Based on Condition in pyspark

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

[image]

One File has Status_MP_c This column need to Split in same file and need to make sent,open,click columns if it is true will you provide logic in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

> One File has Status_MP_c This column need to Split in same file and need to make sent,open,click columns if it is true will you provide logic in pyspark

You can use pivot here.

I took the same data as dataframe.

[image]

As you want to make columns of `sent`, `Open` like that, use pivot on that column like below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
res_df=df.groupBy("MP").pivot("Status").agg(first("res"))
display(res_df)
```

[image]

Whatever the values in the 3rd column of your data whether it is True or False, those will be converted like above.

If you don't want a column with False you can drop that column if the value in the column is False (Or) you can delete the rows which have False in that column before Pivot as well.